# Get aplitude curve from audio

Tags: audio, mp3, decode, amplitude, mpeg

I am using libmpg123 library for parsing and decoding mp3 song, but I want draw something like this:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v627/Flabbergast/jurafirstCDpressing-1.jpg

How can I get an amplitude from mp3 song? I am trying to find solution in a lot of pages but without good result.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: You just plot the sample values against time - which part of this are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: I have a problem with parsing song... I found ringdroid app which draw aplitude curve, but in some reason (I still dont know why...), loud song have less frame gains against to soundless song.